# no system-message by registration

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm using Joomla 3.4.8. The Template is "foodworld". In case of registration, the user get no error-message or success message. Nothing. But the Registration is working. This is independent from the Joomla version. What can I do?

Comment: Is it just on registration? Or are you not getting messages with everything else? Try logging in with the wrong password to see

Comment: If I logging with wrong Password, then is displayed a side with completed form for entering username and password . In addition "forgot password?", "forgot user name?" and "no account?" (or similar, this is in German). Here I can enter user Name and Password again. No other message.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to switch to default template like Protostar. Do you have the same issue?
if you can't replicate the issue with Protostar the problem is on your template

In your site, have you those directories ?

> /templates/foodworld/html/mod_login
>
> /templates/foodworld/html/com_users/login

if yes, rename them one by one to

> /templates/foodworld/html/mod_login_test
>
> /templates/foodworld/html/com_users/login_test

By doing this you are back to the default layout. Is the issue gone?

if yes, the problem is inside of one of this override.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My first question is: if I Change to Protostar, can I Change back to foodworld without any problem?

Comment: The second: "/templates/foodworld/html/mod_Login/" I found. But in Templates I could not found "inetis". In "components" I found "com_users/Controllers/Registration.php".  Is this from te Template?

Comment: The second question: "/templates/foodworld/html/mod_Login/" I found. But in Templates I could not find "inetis". In "Templates" I see only: breez3, foodworld, protostar, system. But in "components" I found "com_users/Controllers/Registration.php".  Is this from the Template?

Comment: ----------------

Comment: sorry inetis folder was a typo
yes you  can change the template at anytime

Comment: Before we continue the discussion, I want test the correctly working registration procedure. Can you name a URL for a Jooomla Protostar (or similar) site for a test.